# Formatting Lost When Creating List Item

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, multiline-text-field

I'm trying to create a list item but the most basic formating is being removed from the input.  Field type is   Multiple lines of text and I've tried using Plain, Rick and Enhanced.

Script to create a list item and populate a field:

```
        $List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listTitle)
        $Context.Load($List)
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()

        $ListItemInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation 
        $ListItem = $List.AddItem($ListItemInfo)

        $ListItem = $List.AddItem($ListItemInfo)
        $ListItem["Title"] = $myVar.Title
        $ListItem["BodyStuff"] = $myVar.SomeStuff   
        $ListItem.Update()  
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

myVar.SomeStuff is populated with the following

> Hello blah,
>
> This is a test message.
>
> Thank you,
>   blahblah
>
> some other random text

When the item is created in SharePoint, the value of myVar.SomeStuff is compressed together removing any line breaks or formatting.

BodyStuff will look like this:
    Hello blah, This is a test message. Thank you, blahblah some other random text

Comment: Have You tried using `\r\n` or `<br>` characters as line breaks?

Comment: When using `PlainText` simple newlines (i.e. `\r\n`) are used. For RichText and "Enhanced" `html` is needed (i.e. `<br>`)

Comment: @KristapsVilerts   yes, i tried it but it didn't work.  Example:  $desc = $myVar.SomeStuff.Replace("\r\n", "<br>")  $ListItem["BodyStuff"] = $desc _____ also tried:   $myVar.SomeStuff.ToString().Replace("\r\n", "<br>")

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I got to work.

```
$myVar.SomeStuff.Replace([Environment]::NewLine, "<br>")
```

@KristapsVilerts  thank you for the input.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked! :) Please mark Your own answer as a "solution" via green check mark.

Answer (score 0):

While updating Multi line of text with HTML you have to pass html rather than just formatted text.

So in your case the SomeStuff should be html in form of string.

```
 $myVar.SomeStuff  ="<p>Hello blah,</p><p>This is a test message.</p><p>Thank you, blahblah</p><p>some other random text .....<span> text in span </span></p>";
```